# When measuring algorithms time complexity, is the time taken to obtain input always omitted?

Tags: algorithm, time, big-o, time-complexity

Since reading input must take Θ(n) then how is it possible some algorithms are faster? For example Binary Search is O(log n) but to read the array or list or whatever is being searched must take Θ(n) (it's not as if you can skip reading certain input). Are algorithms always measured assuming they have input? I don't really see the point of this because the whole point of time complexity is to find the bottle neck. If my question doesn't make sense please say so.

Comment: Binary search is O(log n)

Comment: Getting input isn't part of the algorithm.  The algorithm is what you do with the input after you get it.

Comment: In binary search you do skip reading a big part of the list where you are searching, since you know it's sorted. Why reading all the left side of the list when you know that what you search can only be on the right?

Comment: @naitoon that's not my point. The list must have been read at sometime so that right there is O(n).

Comment: @Celeritas The complexity analysis for binary search assumes that you already have a sorted list.  How you got it and how long it might have taken to create and sort it are not factored into the analysis of binary search.  But yes, you are correct in saying that the creation of such a list would take at least O(n) time.  In order to see why we would want that, imagine you just wrote a binary search function in C that took a pointer to an already sorted array and proceeded to search for a requested element.  Then the amount of time your function would take should be proportional to O(log n)

Comment: first, if obtaining the input is part of the algorithm .. then if it is constant; then yes, constants are omitted in Big-O .. also consider that Big-O is for comparing algorithms; so, compared algorithms should have respective general tasks .. most  algorithms start with "Given .. as input" which shows O(0) for input at Time 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, an algorithm's runtime does not include the time required to prepare the data for processing.  There's no fundamental reason why it has to be this way, though it is nice because for algorithms that take sublinear time (for example, the O(log n) runtime of binary search), we don't want to account for the amount of work required to prepare and sort the array first.

This approach does have several advantages.  Imagine that you want to perform some operation many, many times (such as a binary search).  If the complexity of binary search included the cost required to prepare and sort the array, then we couldn't get the runtime of "perform k binary searches" by taking the runtime of binary search and multiplying by k.  We'd have to take the runtime of binary search, subtract out the work required to prepare the input, multiply that by k, then add back in the one-time cost associated with setting everything up.

That said, runtime analysis usually **does** include the amount of time required to generate the **output**.  For example, if you have an algorithm that produces a list of n values, it must take at least Ω(n) time because you can't actually write out n values without doing n units of work.  This cost is usually accounted for when analyzing the algorithm in the first place.  You can sometimes use this fact to show that algorithms with certain runtimes can't exist; for example, there can't be an algortihm that generates the first n powers of two in time less than Ω(n), because you can't write out that many numbers that quickly.

The fact that we typically skip the setup time for a problem has its roots way back with Turing machines, where the input was assumed to be written down on the tape before the Turing machine even begins its operation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Downvoter- Can you let me know what I can do to improve this answer?  Is there anything in particular that's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

Algorithms measured what they do to input values. Reading input is not a part of algorithm.
And note that algorithm itself and a program that read an input and use this algorithm is different.

for example binary search has O(logn) complexity but a program that read numbers from a file and appliying binary search to find a number has O(logn)+O(n) = O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes sense. Complexity depends on how you define the cost of the algorithm. The definition tries to capture the value added by the algorithm to the World. With that in mind, you can choose to consider the time spent loading (and maybe sorting) the list in Binary Search as part of the cost of the algorithm. It can make sense, specially if you have an estimation on the number of search operations you'll perform along the whole computing session you are analyzing.